# Send a command to an ubuntu server from my website

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, web, command

I have a wordpress website (I can make a new one if its not compatible) I want to send a command from there to my remote ubuntu server how would I do this.

Comment: What kind of command are you trying to send? Where is your ubuntu server (is it publicly accessible)? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Im trying to send a service start command it is a ubuntu 16 server that has publicly accessible apache

Answer (score 0):

Your issue will be that to start the service you need escalated privileges. You'll need to add an exception to your sudoers.

You could add something like this to /etc/sudoers.d/mycommand

```
Defaults:www-data !requiretty
Cmnd_Alias MYCOMMAND = /usr/bin/service myservice start
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:MYCOMMAND
```

Then you can use a php command such as

exec("/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/service myservice start");

Comment: This only works on the local machine, not a remote server. Also, remotely executing code (especially from a website, and as root!) is usually considered a Really Bad Idea.